# Validar si uno de los radiobutton esten seleccionados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este código:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#myBtn").click(function () {  
        if( $("#formulario input[name='radio']:radio").is(':checked')) {  
            $("#formulario").submit();  
            } else{  
                alert("Selecciona un metodo de pago.");  
                }  
    });
 });
```

El problema es que la `alert` se muestra al darle al boton para hacer el registro estando uno seleccionado.
Funciona bien hasta ese punto.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi caso como era solo dos radio button. En tal caso, basta con validar que alguno de los dos esté checked. Debido que al hacerlo de las maneras que encontré en Internet validaba que todos estuvieran checked no una de esas opciones.

Aquí mi código:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  

    $("#myBtn").click(function() {  
        if($("#boton1").is(':checked') || $("#boton2").is(':checked')) {  

        } else {  
            alert("Seleccione un metodo de pago.");  
        }  
    });  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero esto te ayude saludos

```js
$("#enviar").click(function(){
  if( $("#formulario input[type='radio']").is(':checked')) {  
            $("#formulario").submit();  
            alert("enviar formulario")
            } else{  
                alert("Selecciona un metodo de pago.");  
                }  
})

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#myBtn").click(function () {  
        
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formulario">
  <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radios" value="">
  <label for="radio1">pago1</label>
  <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radios" value="">
  <label for="radio2">pago2</label>


<input id="enviar" type="submit" name="" value="Enviar">
</div>
```

Comment: El id del boton es #myBtn no enviar.

Comment: claro amigo es solo un ejemplo no tengo los datos a donde enviar